# Unable to set JSON Objects in RecyclerView that has null objects

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to parse JSON data from newsapi.org. This is a sample json that i'm trying to display in recyclerview

```
"articles":[  
  {  
     "source":{  
        "id":"fox-news",
        "name":"Fox News"
     },
     "author":null,
     "title":"After the hurricane comes the deluge on South Carolina coast",
     "description":"Eleven days ago, Lee Gantt was at a Hurricane Florence party in her neighborhood in Georgetown, where the story goes that some houses haven't flooded from the Sampit River since they were built before the American Revolution.",
     "url":"http://www.foxnews.com/us/2018/09/25/after-hurricane-comes-deluge-on-south-carolina-coast.html",
     "urlToImage":null,
     "publishedAt":"2018-09-25T04:20:37Z",
     "content":"GEORGETOWN, S.C. – Eleven days ago, Lee Gantt was at a Hurricane Florence party in her neighborhood in Georgetown, where the story goes that some houses haven't flooded from the Sampit River since they were built before the American Revolution. She will spend… [+4401 chars]"
  }
```

The code that i have tried. I am unable to display the required contents in Recyclerview. The app crashes with fatal exception. The logcat points the error at onBindViewHolder in the Adapter class.

In the MainActivity in the else statement if i change to return; the recyclerview shows nothing

MainActivity.java

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(sResponse);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("articles");
                for (int k = 0; k < jsonArray.length(); k++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(k);
                    HeadlinesListItem listItem = new HeadlinesListItem();
                    listItem.setsTitle(jsonObject1.getString("title"));
                    if (!jsonObject1.isNull("urlToImage")) {
                        listItem.setsUrlToImage(jsonObject1.getString("urlToImage"));
                    } else {
                        listItem.setsUrlToImage(null);
                    }
                    mNewsList.add(listItem);
```

Adapter.java

```
private Context context;
private List<HeadlinesListItem> mNewsItems;
private MyAdapterListener myAdapterListener;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflator;

TopHeadlinesAdapter(Context context, List<HeadlinesListItem> mNewsItems, MyAdapterListener clickListener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mNewsItems = mNewsItems;
    mLayoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    myAdapterListener = clickListener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.top_headlines_adapter, viewGroup, false);
    return new CustomViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    CustomViewHolder myHolder = (CustomViewHolder) viewHolder;
    HeadlinesListItem listItems = mNewsItems.get(i);
    myHolder.lblHedLine.setText(listItems.getsTitle());
    if (listItems.getsUrlToImage().isEmpty()) {
        Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.noimage).into(myHolder.imgImage);
    }else{
        Glide.with(context).load(listItems.getsUrlToImage()).apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.noimage)).into(myHolder.imgImage);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mNewsItems.size();
}
```

Logcat

```
09-25 12:16:25.867 28309-28309/com.example.rahul.newsapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.rahul.newsapp, PID: 28309
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07006c
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2345)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1850)
    at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(ResourcesCompat.java:82)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.DrawableDecoderCompat.loadDrawableV4(DrawableDecoderCompat.java:76)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.DrawableDecoderCompat.getDrawable(DrawableDecoderCompat.java:64)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.DrawableDecoderCompat.getDrawable(DrawableDecoderCompat.java:41)
    at com.bumptech.glide.request.SingleRequest.loadDrawable(SingleRequest.java:388)
    at com.bumptech.glide.request.SingleRequest.getPlaceholderDrawable(SingleRequest.java:369)
    at com.bumptech.glide.request.SingleRequest.begin(SingleRequest.java:262)
    at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestTracker.runRequest(RequestTracker.java:44)
    at com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager.track(RequestManager.java:614)
    at com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder.into(RequestBuilder.java:646)
    at com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder.into(RequestBuilder.java:706)
    at com.example.rahul.newsapp.TopHeadlinesAdapter.onBindViewHolder(TopHeadlinesAdapter.java:48)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3336)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18557)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18557)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:2017)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:487)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18557)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18557)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18557)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18557)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.
```

Comment: what is the Exception ? post log.

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: For testing purpose try to load any other image like ic_launcher or any else.

Comment: for some of the imgUrl json objects the value is null. This is the main cause of the error.

Comment: @rahulramakrishnan answer is working or not?

Comment: i removed the noimage png from drawableV24 to drawable folder. It now works by doing like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There Problem is That you are setting a null Image url to Glide

"urlToImage":null, //Json Response

Here your else part getting executed

```
        if (!jsonObject1.isNull("urlToImage")) {
                 listItem.setsUrlToImage(jsonObject1.getString("urlToImage"));
                } else {
                    listItem.setsUrlToImage(null);
```

```html
 if (listItems.getsUrlToImage().isEmpty()) {
        Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.noimage).into(myHolder.imgImage);
    }else{
        Glide.with(context).load(listItems.getsUrlToImage()).apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.noimage)).into(myHolder.imgImage);
//You are getting null here
    }
```

Here you are getting error because you put the Drawable in drawableV24 and not in drawable put the image in drawable

```
Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.noimage).into(myHolder.imgImage);
```

Comment: putting the image in the correct drawable folder solved the issue

Comment: @rahulramakrishnan accept as answer so it help others

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this into adapter

```
    String imageUrl = listItems.getsUrlToImage();
    if (imageUrl == null) {
        Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.noimage).into(myHolder.imgImage);
    }else{
        Glide.with(context).load(imageUrl).apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.noimage)).into(myHolder.imgImage);
    }
```

Comment: If still, you are facing the same issue then please replace any other image from drawable.